# android application not open in release mode when mfp-plugin is installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

When generating a release apk for android (ionic project)

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

- the apk is signed with jarsigner and zipped with zipalign

it not work if mfp-plugin installed.

The application is working in two cases

- mfp-plugin installed and the apk is debug mode
- mfp-plugin not installed and the apk is debug or release

what I need is to make it work in release mode and mfp plugin installed.

after the application is opened it closed directly 
and here is the log from logcat

```
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f: a$f.uncaughtException in SourceFile:454 :: Uncaught Exception
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.addof.app/com.addof.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview. 
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview. 
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(SourceFile:82)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebViewEngine(SourceFile:206)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView(SourceFile:202)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(SourceFile:146)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at com.addof.app.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:27)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  ... 9 more
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(SourceFile:78)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  ... 16 more
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.addof.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.addof.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  ... 20 more
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:      ... 21 more
05-21 12:27:58.440 10869 10887 E com.worklight.common.a$f:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.addof.app, PID: 10869
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.addof.app/com.addof.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview. 
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview. 
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(SourceFile:82)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebViewEngine(SourceFile:206)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView(SourceFile:202)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(SourceFile:146)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.addof.app.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:27)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(SourceFile:78)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 16 more
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.addof.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.addof.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 20 more
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 21 more
05-21 12:27:58.445 10869 10869 E AndroidRuntime:    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
05-21 12:27:58.450  4203  4644 D WindowAnimator: Skip setting animation background if there is an exiting window only.
05-21 12:27:58.455  4203  5462 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.addof.app/.MainActivity
05-21 12:27:58.455  4203  5462 D FocusedStackFrame: Set to : 0
05-21 12:27:58.455  4203  5462 D InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
05-21 12:27:58.495  4203 10889 E android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
05-21 12:27:58.495  4203 10889 E android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
05-21 12:27:58.495  4203 10889 E android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
05-21 12:27:58.500  4203  4509 D ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{510da58 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
05-21 12:27:58.500  4203  4509 D ISSUE_DEBUG: InputChannelName : 6ce9496 Application Error: com.addof.app
05-21 12:27:58.505  4203  4509 V MARsPolicyManager: handelAlertToastWindowStarted pkgName = android
05-21 12:27:58.505  4203  4509 D InputDispatcher: Focus entered window: 4203
05-21 12:27:58.505  4203  4644 D PointerIcon: setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001 iconType:101 flag:0 pid:4203 uid:1000
05-21 12:27:58.505  4203  4644 D PointerIcon: setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
05-21 12:27:58.505  4203  4644 D PointerIcon: setHoveringSpenIconStyle1 pointerType: 10001 iconType:1 flag:0 pid:4203 uid:1000
05-21 12:27:58.505  4203  4644 D PointerIcon: setHoveringSpenCustomIcon IconType is same.1
05-21 12:27:58.520  4203  4506 V BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{93f2817 u0 android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{d3f6cc5 13373:com.samsung.android.sm/1000}
05-21 12:27:58.535  3233  3233 I SurfaceFlinger: id=143 createSurf (193x193),1 flag=4, bpp
05-21 12:27:58.535 13373 13373 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1305 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:606 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:606 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.b:259 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.onReceive:107 
05-21 12:27:58.555  4203  4974 D libEGL  : eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x92f607c4
05-21 12:27:58.555  4203  4974 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-21 12:27:58.560  4203  4974 D mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1528x918]-format:1
05-21 12:27:58.560  4203  4509 D StatusBarManagerService: manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{6ce9496 u0 d0 Application Error: com.addof.app}
05-21 12:27:58.565  4203  6054 V BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{93f2817 u0 android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{ae9fefb 5892:com.google.android.gms/u0a17}
05-21 12:27:58.575  4203  4509 W DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-21 12:27:58.600  4203  7025 V BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{93f2817 u0 android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{1012bcb 6180:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a17}
05-21 12:27:58.600  4203  4215 I art     : Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 143195(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 96(3MB) LOS objects, 26% free, 43MB/59MB, paused 2.522ms total 123.111ms
05-21 12:27:58.610  3233 10338 I SurfaceFlinger: id=139 Removed Mauncher (3/10)
05-21 12:27:58.610  3233  3388 I SurfaceFlinger: id=139 Removed Mauncher (-2/10)
05-21 12:27:58.615  4203  4509 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{6ce9496 u0 d0 Application Error: com.addof.app}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
05-21 12:27:58.615  3233  3233 D libEGL  : eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xbed19464
05-21 12:27:58.615  3233  3233 D libEGL  : eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xbed193fc
05-21 12:27:58.630  4203  4509 D ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
05-21 12:27:58.640  4203  4509 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{6ce9496 u0 d0 Application Error: com.addof.app}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
05-21 12:27:58.640  4998  4998 D PhoneStatusBar: setSystemUiVisibility vis=8000 mask=ffffffff oldVal=8600 newVal=8000 diff=600
```

The output of ioinc --info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 23 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.1
   NodeJS     : v11.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.0
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

MFP Plugin version 8.0.2019050614

Steps to reproduce

```
ionic start testApp blank
cd testApp
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
ionic cordova build android --release
cd platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release
keytool -genkey -v -keystore app_key_sign.keystore -alias app_key_sign -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore app_key_sign.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk app_key_sign
 ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/*/zipalign  -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk release.apk
adb install release.apk
```

- zipalign path on mac devices

Comment: Provide basic info: a) ionic version b) MFP plugin version c) Android API Level the application has been built against d) Android device OS version where you the saw the issue

Comment: Provide reproducing steps  starting from the apk  signed with jarsigner and zipped with zipalign to running ionic cordova build android --release command

Comment: @VivinK I updated the ionic and mfp version

Comment: @VivinK it's not working on all devices and emulators of android

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar i added the steps to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding following lines in `proguard-project.txt` file and check

```
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** { *; } 
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*
```

Comment: where is this file? I cannot find it. if I will create it, please let me know what the path

Comment: It will be present under path ../project_name/platforms/android/proguard-project-mfp.txt

Comment: For cordova android 8.x.x it will be present under path 
project_name/platforms/android/app/src/main

Comment: Thanks it work fine, I added this lines into platforms/android/app/src/main/proguard-project-mfp.txt `-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** { *; }`
`-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*`
`-keep class plugin.google.maps.** { *; }`

Answer (score 0):

Add **--prod** and try:

```
ionic cordova build android --release --prod
```

--prod uses the production configuration